# QML/OSM. How to display circle?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, openstreetmap

I have a map and I need to display on her circle. As well as the position of this circle will change during execution of the program from C++/Qt code. How can I do that?

**map.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9

import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Rectangle {
    Plugin {
        id: osmMapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 10

        MapPolyline {
            id: pl
            line.width: 2
            line.color: 'red'
        }
    }

    function loadPath() {
        var lines = [];
        if (pl.pathLength() < pathController.geopath.size()) {
            lines = pl.path;
            for(var i = pl.pathLength(); i < pathController.geopath.size(); i++) {
                lines[i] = pathController.geopath.coordinateAt(i)
            }
        } else {
            for(var i = 0; i < pathController.geopath.size(); i++) {
                lines[i] = pathController.geopath.coordinateAt(i)
            }
        }

        return lines;
    }

    Connections {
        target: pathController
        onGeopathChanged: pl.path = loadPath()
    }

    Component.onCompleted: pl.path = loadPath()
}
```

I tried to add a field `circle` for the `map`, but it was not successful. Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a circle in the map you need to use [MapCircle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapcircle.html), if you want to manipulate your position from C ++ it is appropriate to create a class that controls your position and radius, an example I show you next:

```
class CircleController: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QGeoCoordinate center READ center NOTIFY centerChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal radius READ radius WRITE setRadius NOTIFY radiusChanged)
public:
    CircleController(QObject *parent=0):QObject(parent){
        mCircle.setRadius(1000);
    }
    void setCenter(const QGeoCoordinate &center){
        if(mCircle.center() == center)
            return;
        mCircle.setCenter(center);
        emit centerChanged();
    }
    QGeoCoordinate center() const{ return mCircle.center();}

    void translate(double degreesLatitude, double degreesLongitude){
        mCircle.translate(degreesLatitude, degreesLongitude);
        emit centerChanged();
    }

    qreal radius() const{ return mCircle.radius();}
    void setRadius(const qreal &radius){
        if(mCircle.radius() == radius)
            return;
        mCircle.setRadius(radius);
        emit radiusChanged();
    }
signals:
    void centerChanged();
    void radiusChanged();
private:
    QGeoCircle mCircle;
};
```

Then it is passed to QML through `setContextProperty()`:

```
CircleController circleController;
circleController.setCenter(QGeoCoordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)); // new position

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("circleController", &circleController);
```

Then connect the radio and the center of the controller and the `MapCircle` in QML:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Plugin {
        id: osmMapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }
    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 10

        MapCircle {
            center: circleController.center
            radius: circleController.radius
            color: 'green'
            border.width: 3
        }
    }
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48151862) you will find an example